# SingleChildScrollView does not scroll on iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I do compile and debug my current Flutter app using native MacOS. Works fine.

If I compile to web, upload it to a web server and test it on **iOS Safari or iOS Chrome**, a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `ListView.builder` as child does not scroll. Oversvations in detail:

- Using one finger, I'm able to make it move up a bit, around 1 cm.
- At a certain paint, the view scrolls less than the finger moved.
- Finally, as soon as I lift my finger, the view moves back to its
  initial position.

On MacOS as native target or MacOS using Chrome, the view vertically scrolls just fine.

Tried to google a description regarding this problem, but failed.

**Could someone propose a hint regarding further reading or a workaround?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to listview

`physics : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),`

Since listview and SingleChildScrollView both have scroll it doesnt work as expected. If you stop the listview scroll then it should let SingleChildScrollView scroll as expected

Comment: Kaushik, you saved my day! Works! Tried various changes, read the flutter docs, but nowhere found anything. Did I missed something?

Comment: Glad to know it worked :). Yeah normally you would not need a SingleChildScrollView over a listview but sometimes if you have a column with other children widgets plus the listview in it then we use a SingleChildScrollView but it doesnt scroll unless the listview scroll is stopped

Comment: Kaushik , hm, good point too! Removed the SingleChildScrollView and it still scrolls :-) Don't ask, why I added the SingleChildScroll View ;-)

Comment: Nice :) lol i won't. I learnt it the hard way too haha

Comment: Already invested quite much time in this issue. Although, I should mention, that I test / debug 95% using the MacOS target. And this is one of two issues found yet. Not too bad.

Comment: This is the other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944999/form-input-field-obscured-by-ios-keyboard-widget-not-scrolling-up-as-much-as-n ;-)