# Form input field obscured by iOS keyboard widget / not scrolling up as much as needed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

On iOS and iPadOS, my flutter app shows certain dialogs to let the user add data into form fields.

As native MacOS target, even if the window has a small height, the Dialog gets a scrollbar to navigate to each input field.

- On Safari and Chrome on iOS and iPadOS, the Dialog gets obscured partly, if the virtual keyboard appears.
- Then, I'm not able to scroll far enough up to reach each input field.
- As if the dialog gets stopped at the top at a certain point.

**What do I have to prepare the app in this case?**

PS: Could someone propose an info-page, which explains sich **platform specific effects and solutions / workarounds**?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have these form input inside a Column widget. The best practice is to create a bound (Sizedbox or SafeArea) -> ScrollView -> input fields

For example

```
SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: SingleChildScrollView (
   child: Column(
     children: [
      SizedBox(height: 600),
      //All widgets here
      TextField(), // this textfield will move above the keyboard automatically upon receiving focus.
     ]
   )
  )

)
```

Comment: Do you mean, that SizedBox(height: 600) does not appear, since the TextField() immediately gets move to the to of the dialog? As soon as it gets focus? Or as soon as the form / dialog gets displayed?

Comment: I added sized box to move the textfield down. When textfield gets focus it should automatically scroll and make the textfield appear above the keyboard